# UseReducer dispatch function throws unexpected error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Couldn't find any related answer, the only one was related to Redux directly, thus asking a question that may seem obvious to some of you.
As far as my code it seems that everything is correct yet I'm struggling with the following error: **Expected 0 arguments, but got 1**

Code:

```js
 // An enum with all the types of actions to use in our reducer
  enum ActionType {
    INCREASE = 'INCREASE',
  }

  // An interface for our actions
interface Action {
  types: ActionType;
  payload: number;
}

// An interface for our state
interface allState {
  playersNumber: number,
  playerData: string
}


const reducer : any = (state : allState, action : Action) => {
    switch (action.types) {
      case ActionType.INCREASE:
        return { playersNumber: state.playersNumber + 5}
    }
  }

  const initialState = {
    playersNumber : 0,
    playerData: ""
  }

const App : FC<any> = () => {
  const [responseData , setResponseData] = useState<Array<object>>([]);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);


  // Fetching data with Axios
  const fetchingData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get<Array<object>>('http://localhost:3006/lfy');
    setResponseData(response.data);
    console.log(response.data.length);
    dispatch({type: ActionType.INCREASE})
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <Routes>
      {console.log(state)}
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It seems like there is a typo when you call the `dispatch` function - the argument should be `{types:ActionType.INCREASE}` instead of `type`

Comment: This is a known issue for Jetbrains' IDE's:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53963/Dispatch-function-from-Reacts-useReducer-reports-wrong-argument-requirements

Answer (score 0):

You are quite there! There is only a few things to fix. First, you need to remove the type **any** from the reducer and always return the whole state inside the function:

```
const reducer = (state : allState, action : Action) => {
 switch (action.types) {
  case ActionType.INCREASE:
   return {...state, playersNumber: state.playersNumber + 5}; // use the shallow copy for the state so you make sure to not replace it completely
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

Ultimately, when you call dispatch you wrote *type* instead of **types** and you also did not pass the payload. If the payload is optional you have to set it as optional in the interface:

```
interface Action {
  types: ActionType;
  payload?: number; // note the question mark
}
```

```
dispatch({types: ActionType.INCREASE});
```